# Setting default date format for PostgreSQL connection in Laravel

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

When I try to get a list of Eloquent model objects in JSON format from my Laravel controller, I run into an error:

```
 InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 393:
 Trailing data
```

Relevant parts of the stack trace are:

```
1. in Carbon.php line 393
2. at Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2015-04-20 18:07:13.769') in Model.php line 2889
3. at Model->asDateTime('2015-04-20 18:07:13.769') in Model.php line 2392
4. at Model->attributesToArray() in Model.php line 2371
```

Seems that the root of my problem is that when serializing the model to JSON it's trying to parse the value of one of the timestamp columns to create a Carbon object (which I suppose will then be converted back to a string) but it's using the wrong format.

The format string is coming from `Model::getDateFormat()` which by default is:

```
$this->getConnection()->getQueryGrammar()->getDateFormat()
```

and is turning out to be `'Y-m-d H:i:s'` instead of what what PostgreSQL is giving which is  `'Y-m-d H:i:s.u'` (or something, not sure if milliseconds and microseconds are interchangeable like that). Of course it's possible to just override `getDateFormat()` in all of my model classes but that's annoying (and not really the correct place for it, as the model should be fairly database-independent), even if I just have them all inherit from a base class. Is there a way to set the query grammar's date format instead? Seems like it should be possible through the database config file but I couldn't find anything in the documentation about this.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly via db config files, but you might consider telling Postgres not to save milliseconds in the database at all:

```
ALTER TABLE {tablename} ALTER updated_at SET DATA TYPE timestamp(0) without time zone;
```

The other option is to override PostgresGrammar class and its getDateFormat() method but it didn't work for me on laravel 4.2